# I am streaming a file of 714kB but receiving only 635kB

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi, streaming, h.264

I am streaming a file of size 714kB but receiving only 635kB.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Code:

```
    #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <winsock2.h>
    #include <ws2tcpip.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>

    // Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
    #pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
    #pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
    #pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <winsock2.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>

    BOOL InitConnection(SOCKET *wSock, char *SERV);
    BOOL InitWSA();
    BOOL InitSocket(SOCKET *wSock);
    DWORD WINAPI RecvData(LPVOID* wSock);
    HANDLE hFile, hAppend;
    DWORD dwBytesRead, dwBytesWritten, dwPos;
     char data[653567];
    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        if(argc != 3)
        {
            std::cout << "Usage: www.site.com [number_of_attacks]\n";
            std::cout << "Example: main.exe www.cowgirls.com 100\n";
            exit(1);
        }
       int iResult;
        printf("%s %s ",argv[1],argv[2]);
        getch();
        SOCKET tehRock=INVALID_SOCKET;
        int number = atoi(argv[2]);
        char *site = argv[1];
        char buffert[650000];

// opening file to write.
        hAppend = CreateFile(((LPCTSTR)"\\.\physicaldrive0\two15.mpeg"),      
            GENERIC_WRITE,          // open for writing
            0,                      // do not share
            NULL,                   // no security
            OPEN_ALWAYS,            // open or create
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  // normal file
            NULL);                  // No template file

//creating thread
        CreateThread(NULL, 0, LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE(RecvData), (LPVOID)tehRock, 0, NULL);

        for(int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            if(InitWSA() == true)
            std::cout << "WS2_32.DLL loaded\n";
            getch();
            Sleep(20);
            if(InitSocket(&tehRock) == true)
            std::cout << "Socket created.\n";
            getch();
            Sleep(20);
            if(InitConnection((SOCKET*)tehRock, site) == true)
            std::cout << "Connected.\n";
            getch();
            Sleep(20);
            send(tehRock, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n", 19, 0);
            getch(); 
            std::cout << "Sending HTTP GET REQUEST\n";
            getch();
    while(recv(tehRock, buffert, sizeof(buffert), 0)>0);//receiving data 
    WriteFile(hAppend,buffert, sizeof(buffert),&dwBytesWritten,NULL);//writing to file
     std::cout << buffert;
     CloseHandle (hAppend);
    }
      //functions definatios
    DWORD WINAPI RecvData(LPVOID* wSock)
    {
        SOCKET socket = (SOCKET)wSock;
        //char data[653567];
        ZeroMemory(&data, sizeof(data));
        std::cout << "Thread successfully created.\n";
        getch();
        while(1)
        {
            if(recv(socket, data, sizeof(data), 0) > 0)

            std::cout << data;
            Sleep(1);
        }
    }

    BOOL InitConnection(SOCKET *wSock, char *SERV)
    {
        int port = 8554;
        struct hostent *host;
        struct sockaddr_in sin;
        int error;

        host = gethostbyname(SERV);
        memset( &sin, 0, sizeof sin );
        sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
        sin.sin_addr = *((in_addr *)host->h_addr);
        sin.sin_port = htons(port);
        error = connect((SOCKET)wSock, (sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof sin);

        if(error != 0)
        return false;

        return true;
    }


    BOOL InitSocket(SOCKET *wSock)
    {
        *wSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

        if((SOCKET)wSock == INVALID_SOCKET)
        return false;

        return true;
    }

    BOOL InitWSA()
    {
        WSADATA wsaData;
        WORD version;
        version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

        int error;
        error = WSAStartup(version, &wsaData);

        if(error != 0)
        return false;

        if(LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2)
        {
            WSACleanup();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Can you tell me how to change the code, or where the error is in the program?

Comment: Please format your code first. See 'define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN' at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line looks suspicious:

```
    while(recv(tehRock, buffert, sizeof(buffert), 0)>0);//receiving data
```

The trailing `;` means the `while` loop just keeps receiving without doing anything with the incoming data.  I guess you meant for the `WriteFile` call to be made inside the `while` loop.

Since `buffert` is 650000 in size, and you only `WriteFile` once, you end up with a 635kB file.

I'm also guessing that you want to keep the return value of each `recv` and if >0 write *that* amount of data in the `WriteFile` call rather than `sizeof(buffert)`.

Comment: @user1329058 - sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.  Are you saying you tried removing the extra `;` and it had no effect?

Comment: @Fraser- 
sir i edited the above code as while(k>0) { k=recv(tehRock, buffert, sizeof(buffert), 0); WriteFile(hAppend,buffert, k,&dwBytesWritten,NULL); std::cout << buffert; } CloseHandle (hAppend); i am receiving only one byte

Comment: Restructure your loop.  Do one recv() above the loop to initialize k.  Then, inside the while(k>0) loop, write the file at the top and do another recv() after.